# MySql select all for todays day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select query that is:

```
SELECT id FROM entries 
WHERE email_address = ? 
AND created_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
LIMIT 1
```

and it works. But I want to change my `created_date >= ...` to be the last day rather than day + time. Is this possible?

So right now a user cannot enter more than once in a 24 hour period. I want to change it to be a day, so a user could enter at 11:59PM once on a day and then 12:01am immediately the following day.

How can I change my select to account for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert created_date from a datetime to just a date.

```
DATE(created_date) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

BUT watch out for timezones! And doing this will mean the index on created_date is not used, so make sure that doesn't hurt things.

Answer (score 1):

Change `NOW()` to  `CURDATE()`, that should solve your problem.